# Open CRM Entity View with a link

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to open a CRM Entity view from my C# code.

My code gives me the right URL and open the right view, but the problem is the view name displayed is wrong.

for example, my URL opens the view "My Envelopes". The view content is right, but the name displayed is "Actives Envelopes" (which is the default public view). The ViewId is right.

Why ? What is the solution to display the right view name ?

If it's a duplicated question, please give me the answer URL, I haven't found the same issue yet !

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if it might help someone : I just needed to put the View Id in UpperCase...

I really don't know why, but now the view name is good.